# How can I pass Tippy tooltip to icons?

Tags: vue.js, tippyjs

1.I'm trying to implement Tippy in Vue for an icon from Iconify, but unfortunately, it's not working. Does Tippy work on elements other than buttons as well?
2.Is it also possible to pass a conditional statement to such a tooltip?
3. What do you recommend to create a tooltip?

I installed Tippy package.

```
<script setup>
import { useTippy } from "vue-tippy";
const text = ref();

useTippy(text, {
  content: "Hello!",
});
</script>
```

```
<template>
   <Icon icon="moon" ref="text"/>
</template>
```